# Table Join in HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my index...

- Chapter 1 (link)
- Chapter 2 (link)

When I click Chapter 1 or Chapter 2 in my index, it leads me to the [same group of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rdlm.png). The group of questions belong only to [Chapter 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpe6K.png). How do I put Chapter 1 questions in the Chapter 1 link, and Chapter 2 questions in the Chapter 2 link (When I eventually add some).

Here is my first set of code...

```
    <?php
    require_once 'init.php';

    $pollsQuery = $db->query("
        SELECT id, title
        FROM polls_chapters
    ");
    while ($row = $pollsQuery->fetchObject()) {
        $polls_chapters[] = $row;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php if(!empty($polls_chapters)): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($polls_chapters as $poll_chapter): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="questions.php?chapter=<?php echo $poll_chapter->id; ?>"><?php echo $poll_chapter->title; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, nothing is available at the moment.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my second set of code...

```
<?php
    require_once 'init.php';

    $pollsQuery = $db->query("
        SELECT id, question
        FROM polls
        WHERE DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN starts AND ends
    ");
    while ($row = $pollsQuery->fetchObject()) {
        $polls[] = $row;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Questions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php if(!empty($polls)): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($polls as $poll): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="poll.php?poll=<?php echo $poll->id; ?>"><?php echo $poll->question; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, nothing is available at the moment.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to add a `WHERE chapter = " . intval($_GET['chapter']) . "` to your sql

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick response!